# Cannot pull correct time range

Tags: sql, oracle

After executing this query

```
AND TRUNC(ITD.TRAN_DATE)>= '02-APR-18'
AND TO_CHAR(ITD.TRAN_DATE,'HH24MI')>='0600'
AND TRUNC(ITD.TRAN_DATE)<= '03-APR-18'
AND TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ITD.TRAN_DATE+1),'HH24MI')<='0030'
```

Everything after 6AM for April 2nd will show, but also times after 12:30AM the next day shows.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you do a lexical (string) comparison with numeric (incl. date) data it is almost always going to fail. Also, when you `trunc` a datetime, the time part is lost. So last condition is always going to return 0000 and comparison succeeds for all entries.

Comment: I did it that way to use as a parameter in excel.  So theres no way I can add an extra statement to only collect data before 12:30AM?

Answer (score 2):

When we truncate a date we remove the time element. Consequently, a mask of `'HH24:MI'` will return `'00:00'` which means that this will **always be true** regardless of the actual time component of ITD.TRAN_DATE:

```
AND TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ITD.TRAN_DATE+1),'HH24MI')<='0030'
```

Probably what you should do is something more straightforward, such as

```
where itd.tran_date >= date '2018-04-02' + (6/24)
and   itd.tran_date <= date '2018-04-03' + (1/48)
```

Here's [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/086aa/1) comparing your WHERE clause with my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want. Maybe this:

```
and to_char(itd.tran_date, 'YYYYMMDD-HH24MISS')
    between '20180402-0600'
        and '20180403-0030'
```

If so however, and if the table have many rows and `tran_date` is an indexed column, this might be a lot faster:

```
and itd.tran_date
    between to_date('20180402-0600','YYYYMMDD-HH24MI')
        and to_date('20180403-0030','YYYYMMDD-HH24MI')
```

In your question you assume the date_format to be DD-MON-YY. This might be the case now, for the environment you have today, but might not be so always. So it's good practice to use to_char or to_date on `DATE` values or strings.